# Using an API in r

Tags: r, api, url, get

I am using an api to generate gender based on first names; the api address is:

```
https://api.genderize.io/?name=
```

I have created an address for all queries by creating an address for each name (mydata$NameGenderURL). For example I have a url for Peter:

```
https://api.genderize.io/?name=peter
```

My code:

```
mydata$gender <- GET(url= mydata$NameGenderURL)
mynamegenderfunction <- function(x) {
    GET(url= mydata$NameGenderURL[x])
}
genderdata <- mynamegenderfunction(x)
```

Strangely it works when I use mydata$gender <- GET(url= mydata$NameGenderURL[1]), but when I use it in a function or when I use [1:100] it gives me the following message:

> Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Same thing happens for the function: mynamegenderfunction(1) works but mynamegenderfunction(1:100) does not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you are only allowed to provide one url.

Comment: `GET` is not vectorized. Use a loop.

Comment: @Gregor: thanks! used lapply and worked!

Comment: Just an idea, but you might be able to use the gender package in R for what you are trying to do.https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/gender.pdf